# Left align children in a centered dynamic width parent

Tags: html, css

I kinda can't wrap my head around it and it is also hard to find the proper solution on the web/here as it is hard to formulate.

Basically what I want is something like a centered justifiation with left aligned images. So it should be a centered dynamic width parent div (width depends on browser width), which holds divs with images which are presented in a line, but a new line should be left aligned.

I have no problem reaching that goal with [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html).
The centered masonry displays exactly the behavior I want. If you resize the browser, the parent div will adjust its width and the childs will reposition themselves and "fill up a line", staying "centered". But a not "filled up line" will stay left aligned.

Is there a way to reach exactly the same behavior (well without animation that is ^^) of the divs, without using js or anything else? I hope it is kinda clear what I mean. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us the code samples of what you did already?

Comment: Well I don't have any code to show, as the only way I got the behavior to work is with Isotope - which is a jQuery plugin. But I was curious about getting this behavior to work without usage of any additional scripts - as it somehow seems this could be done with CSS only.

Comment: Adding even the basic plugin example in a code block or a jsfiddle might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the correct way to close this question, but I would want to thank everybody responding to my question. So I guess it is not possible to create this behavior only with CSS. jQuery or Media Queries are needed to get the proper behavior.

Here is how I finally resolved the issue (using jQuery actually):
http://jsfiddle.net/Ewtx2/

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='outline'>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
    <div class='innerbox'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px red dashed;
}
#outline {
    text-align: left;
    font-size:0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    /* for ie6/7: */
    *display: inline;
    border: 1px black dashed;
    zoom:1;
}
.innerbox {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

jQuery

```
var boxAmount = 0;
var newWidth = 0;
setNewWidth();

$(window).resize(function() {
    setNewWidth();
});

function setNewWidth() {
    // get container width and check how many boxes fit into it (account margin/padding)
    boxAmount = ($('#container').width() - 5) / ($('.innerbox').width() + 5);
    boxAmount = Math.floor(boxAmount);
    // multiply the box amount with the box width to get the new width to hold the box amount + padding
    if(boxAmount <= $('.innerbox').length) { 
        newWidth = boxAmount * $('.innerbox').width() + boxAmount * 5; 
    }
    // set the new calculated width
    $('#outline').width(newWidth);    
}
```

I wrote a script that takes the container width, divides it by the size of a single box, floors it, which gives us the amount of boxes fitting into the container. Then it multiplies this box amount with the box width, which then gives us the new size for the outline. The new size is set to the outline and thus the outline with all the boxes always stays centered and no strange white space to the right appears.

Comment: To prevent the container from continuously expanding if the screen is large you should add an if around `newWidth = boxAmount...`. Change it to `if(boxAmount <= $('.innerbox').length) { newWidth = boxAmount * $('.innerbox').width() + boxAmount * 5; }`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Ewtx2/1/)

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't check for that case. Thank you very much! Your effort is really welcome and appreciated. Somehow I can first accept my own answer in 2 days, :-S. Strange.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Make sure to update your javascript here and the new jsFiddle link with the `if` fix I mentioned above added in

Comment: one of the best and simplest approaches. I will say better than media queries as it will work with any step of resolution

Answer (score 1):

I did it with pure CSS by adding a couple of container divs around the square elements and playing around with the displays and text-alignment. See a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/yXxD6/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='outline'>
        <div class='innerbox'></div>
        <div class='innerbox'></div>
        <div class='innerbox'></div>
        <!-- As many as you want -->             
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
#outline {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    /* for ie6/7: */
    *display: inline;
    padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;;
    border: 1px black dashed;
    zoom:1;
}
.innerbox {
    display:inline-block;    
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

**Note based on comments below**

There is a space between the right most box and the right of its container when the boxes take up more than one line. Without some sort of javascript this small amount of space is impossible to remove completely

**Edit to add fully functionality using javascript**

Here is my attempt at achieving full functionality using javascript and jQuery: [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/yXxD6/43/). It's still glitching when shrinking the window size due to the added `<br/>`s, but I'll look for a fix and the code might be useful to some users in addition to your answer. I think my solution is slightly more generic than yours though. Glad I could help you get the right idea!

**Pure javascript version added later**

[***Here***](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/yXxD6/51/) is my most recent version of this objective. It is in pure javascript, removes the need for a container, and removes the hard-coded padding values

Comment: make sure you stick an `zoom:1` on #outline as the other half of the IE6/7 fix.

Comment: When you put a few more boxes, fulfilling a line and having some jumping to a second line, that first line doesn't look to be centered as the author requested. Or maybe it's just my eyes.

Comment: I've just confirmed it. Inspect the outline box using Firebug, and see the blank space after the last box on the first line. The first box on the same line doesn't have this blank space before it, which means the line is not centered.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Dragging the window width shows the problem. I realize that is the case, it happens because there is not enough space for another box yet it is leaving room for one. Any idea how to fix it? This is the best I can come up with, it's an acceptable loss IMO

Comment: @Zeaklous I know what you mean, and your solution is the closest I could get too, but that's not what the author is expecting. I have no idea on how to achieve this with just CSS.

Comment: well you just make the width of the boxes a percentage, of course in this case you will have a finite number of boxes per line. I don't think the OP was clear on this requirement

Comment: Thanks guys, this is exactly my problem. The thing you guys are pointing out and Zeaklous correctly noted in his post is my issue. I tried around and I couldn't get rid of this space at the right most boxes. Because basically it is leaving space for another box but the box doesn't fit in there "just yet". So I wonder why it leaves that space to the right. I think this is really strange. Okay so how would you guys solve this issue, if there is no way with only CSS, how would the script look like? @Huangism I actually want to use a fixed width and the amount of boxes per line should be dynamic.

Comment: @chi if you have a fixed width parent then all you need to do is make sure your inner boxes divides evenly into it. If you have a % width for parent and fixed width for inner boxes then this will appear. My suggestion would be to use % width for the inner boxes, and you can use media query to change the inner box width based on different width of the browser. Otherwise you will need js to update the width of the boxes based on the parent width

Comment: @chi this happens because your inner boxes are not technically centered. You can't center them because you need the new line to be left aligned.

Comment: @Huangism Okay, I understand. Thank you. Could you give me an example for your suggestion (how to handle this issue with a media query)?

Comment: @chi I put up an answer, hope it helps

Comment: @Zeaklous this actually looks great. I am also trying to find the issue why it is glitching. This would be the solution I am looking for, if the window resize issue can be somehow resolved.

Comment: @Chi I've been working on it since I posted xD [Here is my most recent update](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/yXxD6/11/). It's not doing much better, but I fixed a couple incorrect things

Comment: @Chi [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/yXxD6/19/) is another version that works well if you start with the window big then go smaller. It works for up to three rows currently. I am now working on making it start small and get big

Comment: @Zeaklous thank you very much for the hard work you are putting into it! I checked your code, but I couldn't get rid of the jumps/glitches. I resolved it and posted the answer here, I hope this is okay. I am pretty new to Stack Overflow ^^.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use media query to handle this then it will probably be something like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280) {
   .innerBox {
        width: 20%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024) {
   .innerBox {
        width: 10%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768) {
   .innerBox {
        width: 5%;
    }
}
```

These width I have are just arbitrary numbers. The width in % are also arbitrary, but if you want the boxes to fit nicely into 100% then they need to be able to divide evenly into 100. I did not include any padding or margin, I am sure you can figure that part out. Please keep in mind that media query is not supported in legacy browsers like IE8 and under. But you can download js plugins to make them work. Google is your friend