# Center image grid on page containing left aligned images

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, center

I have a div that just contains a bunch of 145px X 145px thumbnail images. The div doesn't have a set width so that there is the highest amount of images in one row that your browser window can fit. Now I want to center that div container, but keep the images left aligned. So I can't use text-align: center, because if the last row has fewer images in it, that row will be centered under the rest of the rows. Is there a way to center the container div with css or do I have to use javascript?

I have a jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/eTukegu/3/edit

(I just put 7 thumbnails in for the example, and I used divs instead of images)

```
<div id="thumbnail_container">
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#thumbnail_container
{
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}

.thumbnail
{
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 1px 1px 5px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you also put the code from the jsbin in this question? If jsbin is offline your question becomes useless including its answers.

Comment: You have to use javascript to calculate the extra room to see if there is room for the next element, removing the spare width if so. It is impossible to do with pure CSS because it will always have `width:100%` as it is

Comment: See [**this SO question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833757/left-align-children-in-a-centered-dynamic-width-parent/17834990#17834990), it is *exactly* what you need

Comment: thanks Zach, I ended up writing my own javascript, but that SO question solves my question perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the javascript I wrote to solve this: (my thumbnail images are 145x145 with 10px in between each thumbnail)

```
window.onload = function()
{
    setNewWidth();
};

window.onresize = function ()
{
    setNewWidth();
};

function setNewWidth()
{
    var containerWrapper = document.getElementById('thumbnail_container_wrapper');
    var containerWrapperWidth = containerWrapper.offsetWidth;
    var boxesInRow = Math.floor((containerWrapperWidth - 10) / 155);
    var newWidth = boxesInRow * 155;
    var container = document.getElementById('thumbnail_container');
    container.style.width = newWidth + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using display:table and changing left/right margin to auto:

```
#thumbnail_container{
 display: table;
 margin: 5px auto;
 padding: 0;
}
```